# Amount of time the splash screen should show before iPhone app launches?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, user-experience

My app loads pretty fast. So fast in fact that you actually can't really read anything on it. I was thinking of slowing it down so that people could get a bit of feeling of ***welcome*** before the start using. How long do you think this should be for ? Max? Min?

Keep in mind, my splash screen has very little print on it. It basically has the logo and a ***better with headphones*** recommendation.

Comment: Just a note: It's worth noting that:

the splash stays until your "viewDidLoad" is complete.
As soon as viewDidLoad returns, the splash screen goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app launches quick enough that the splash screen disappears before you can read it, then consider that you may not need to display it at all, especially if it's just a logo.

Your 'better with headphones' text could be displayed in a modal dialog on the first launch of the application to make the user aware of it.

Comment: I like this idea. Any recommendation on how to do that?

Comment: In Application Delegate 
-(BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 

something like
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults boolForKey : @ "FirstL"]){
        [defaults setBool : YES forKey : @ "FirstL"];
        [defaults synchronize]; 
  NSString *msgAlert = @ "Message Here..";
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@ "First Run" message:msgAlert delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@ "OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
         [alertView show];

Answer (score 4):

Please please please do not intentionally slow your users down! This is horrible design and should be avoided at (almost) all times.

Answer (score 1):

We should all have your problem of our applications launching too fast! :-)

You could put up a modal view controller with the same background image as your launch screen, but with a "dismiss" or "OK" button so the user can read the message and then make it go away. I'd recommend doing this only on the first launch, though.

Answer (score 0):

Better you take a UIView showing your text as a Splash Screen. Take 1 `NSTimer`, set it on viewDidLoad method and set the time to call let say 3 seconds. After timer, the timer method will hide the splash screen. Bit of code here,

```
NSTimer *tmrHideSplashScreen = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(hideSplashScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and

```
-(void)hideSplashScreen
{
 splashScreen.hidden = YES;
}
```

where splashScreen is `UIView` containing your text to be shown to users.